# Cant Instance from RepositoryPattern Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i using below repository pattern. when i  instance from the class getting this exception:

```
 public interface IRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : class
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void Attach(TEntity entity);
    void SaveChanges();
    void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options);
}

public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private ObjectContext _context;
    private IObjectSet<TEntity> _objectSet;

    public GenericRepository(ObjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
    {
        return _objectSet;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return GetQuery().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Where<TEntity>(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity Single(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.Single<TEntity>(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity First(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _objectSet.First<TEntity>(predicate);
    }

    public void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _objectSet.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }

        _objectSet.AddObject(entity);
    }

    public void Attach(TEntity entity)
    {
        _objectSet.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    {
        _context.SaveChanges(options);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && _context != null)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            _context = null;
        }
    }
}
```

using:

```
 var db = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();  
 IRepository<Person> person = new GenericRepository<Person>();
```

exception:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you are using Entity Framework 4.1 or later, which has `DbContext` wrapper around `ObjectContext`. But your repository still usess `ObjectContext`. Add another constructor, which accepts `DbContext`:

```
public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
{
    _context = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    _objectSet = _context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
}
```

You can retrieve wrapped `ObjectContext` instance by casting `DbContext` to `IObjectContextAdapter` interface. Another option is updating your repository class to use latest `DbContext`, but that will require a little bit more coding, than simply adding one constructor:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> 
   where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext _context; // instead of ObjectContext
    private DbSet<TEntity> _set; // instead of IObjectSet<TEntity>

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _set = _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetQuery()
    {
        return _set;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return GetQuery().AsEnumerable();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _set.Where<TEntity>(predicate);
    }    

    // etc
}
```

Comment: i dont need add DBContext(AdventureWorks2012Entities) to my class?

Comment: @MeysamSavameri create repository this way `var db = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();  
 IRepository<Person> person = new GenericRepository<Person>(db);`

Answer (score 0):

This is all in the error message, the first one is simple enough - your repository expects an `ObjectContext` parameter (which you don't provide).

The second one is basically saying that your `db` instance is not of type `ObjectContext` or at least can't be downcast to that particular type. If your *sure* `AdventureWorks2012Entities` derives from `ObjectContext` then you could do a direct cast e.g.

```
IRepository<Person> repo = new GenericRepository<Person>((ObjectContext)db);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a DbSet to your repository, so:

```
var db = new AdventureWorks2012Entities();
IRepository<Person> person = new GenericRepository<Person>(db.Person);
```

Where db.Person is declared in the AdventureWorks2012Entities DbContext class.

I'm developing a UnitOfWork/Repository abstraction layer to easily switch from NHibernate/EntityFramework/Raven and others and to better allow the tests.

[Here](http://hyperionsdk.codeplex.com) the source code and [here](http://nuget.org/packages/EyeSoft.Data.EntityFramework) the Nuget package. I've to change the code base to better support [DDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) methodology, in particular:

1. remove the unit of work class, not needed because work with one aggregate per time
2. add the Commit method to the repository